# My Fragment (inside a Viewpager) gots blank when I switched to another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm using in my Secondactivity a Viewpager with a TabLayout toolbar.
In these viewpager with the Id "container" I show four fragments:
HomeActivity, PayActivity, VideoSectionsActivity and BillActivity.

In the fragment VideoSectionsActivity I have a button which should change the content of the VideoSectionsActivity to another content of ActionActivity.

Update:

In case of you overseen this I want to change my Fragment inside a viewpager.

But the code in my VideoSectionsActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class VideoSectionsActivity extends Fragment {

    Button action;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video_sections, container, false);
        action = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.genre_action);

        action.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new VideoActivity()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

doesn't work well. If I click on the button all my fragments changes to blank except for my HomeActivity. Did I used the wrong code or should I do some modifications in my SectionPagerAdapter?

If you need some more code I have to add here so please let me know.

Edit:

If I use getChildFragmentManager() I got this error message:

```
09-21 08:15:05.308 12931-12931/com.example.fdai3744.t_online20 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.fdai3744.t_online20, PID: 12931
                                                                                 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d008e (com.example.fdai3744.t_online20:id/container) for fragment VideoActivity{69c42ef #0 id=0x7f0d008e}
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1293)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `getChildfragmentManager()` ,if your fragment is inside view pager

try below code

```
action.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new VideoActivity()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can't change your fragments inside viewpager. Let me know that, You want to change your VideoSectionsActivity to ActionActivity when you press on the button inside VideoSectionActivity???

Comment: Sry for this confusion. Is there another way to change a fragment inside viewpager?

Comment: It's not possible by doing like this. You can achieve this by using fragmentInteractionLisntener  or broardcast in your button click and change your fragment in your activity by calling viewPager.setCurrentItem(num, true);

Comment: I found a trick to change a fragment inside a viewpager anyway. See below.

Answer (score 1):

replace your fragment by using below code;

```
action.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  Fragment fragment = new VideoActivity();
  FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
  ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
  ft.commit();
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work neither. :( My fragment also turns blank but if I switch the TabLayout to the other fragments and click back then the VideoSectionsActivity turns back.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to solve my problem.
First of all: Very thanks to Vinayak B who mentioned that fragments can't be changed inside ViewPagers.

The trick is you have to load in your viewpager an empty fragment which only includes a FrameLayout with an id.

Then you write in the Java class of your empty fragment:

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.IdOfYourFrameLayout, new FragmentActivity());
    transaction.commit();
```

You can also see this tutorial on: http://www.pineappslab.com/post/fragments-viewpager/